# Dataframe with many years and annual totals [R]

Tags: r, insert, sum, row

I have a large dataframe (AT_df) with many years for many countries, but no annual totals. The initial dataset has already been slimmed down to Pollutant_name (x1="CO2"), I dropped all subcategories, and to one country.

I am preparing this data to afterwards run ggplot2, but for this I need to add a row for each year with the total of the categories (=1-6).

The data looks like this (excerpt):

```
       x     y          x1      x2      x4   x6
1553   1993  0.00000    CO2     Austria  6   6 - Other Sector
1554   2006  0.00000    CO2     Austria  6   6 - Other Sector
1555   2015  0.00000    CO2     Austria  6   6 - Other Sector
2243   1998  12.07760   CO2     Austria  5   5 - Waste management
2400   1992  11.12720   CO2     Austria  5   5 - Waste management
2401   1995  11.11040   CO2     Austria  5   5 - Waste management
2402   2006  10.26000   CO2     Austria  5   5 - Waste management
2489   1998  0.00000    CO2     Austria  6   6 - Other Sector
```

I would like to insert a row which is labelled (x6= aggregate) and sums up the values for y (emissions) under the condition of x= year xyz & x2=country_xyz.

Basically something like this

```
sum(AT_df, x4 %in% c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6") & x ="yearxyz" & 
x2="Austria").
```

This then should be inserted into the dataframe FOR EACH YEAR (16 years in total)

While I have tried some things I've read on stackoverflow, such as:

```
rbind(AT_df, data.frame(x1='Aggregate', y = sum(AT_df$y)))
```

... I was not able to write any correctly working code

Thanks in any case and for any sort of help.

Comment: In general it's not tidy to mix data and summary rows in a data frame. Is there a particular reason you want to do this? I cannot see how it would be needed for anything in ggplot2

Comment: @CalumYou thank you for your quick reply. I need to plot graphs (x=year, y=emissions) for each country. The curves should be for each category (1-6) + one aggregate curve. This is why I wanted to prepare the dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first prepare a data frame with summary data in the same shape as your `AT_df` and afterwards combine the two. There are many ways to do this in R. Here I am using the `dplyr` package. Since the sample data is not enough to fully show this, I am also creating some artificial data first. After that, one has to do the follwing steps:

- Name all the columns that should be retained when summarising (function `group_by`).
- Summarise some column and assigning the output to a column (function `summarise`).
- Add a column for the now missing variable(s) (function `mutate`).
- Combine the resulting data frame with the original one (function `union_all`)

The final `filter` is only used to show some representative data.

```r
set.seed(42)
df <- expand.grid(year = 1993:2015,
                  pollutant = "CO2",
                  country = LETTERS,
                  sector = 1L:6L)

df$amount <- runif(nrow(df), 0, 15)

library("dplyr")
df %>%
  group_by(year, pollutant, country) %>%
  summarise(amount = sum(amount)) %>%
  mutate(sector = -1L) %>%
  union_all(df) %>%
  filter(country == "A" & year == 1996)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#> # Groups:   year, pollutant [1]
#>    year pollutant country amount sector
#>   <int> <fct>     <fct>    <dbl>  <int>
#> 1  1996 CO2       A        41.5      -1
#> 2  1996 CO2       A        12.5       1
#> 3  1996 CO2       A         4.24      2
#> 4  1996 CO2       A         6.70      3
#> 5  1996 CO2       A         1.88      4
#> 6  1996 CO2       A         9.40      5
#> 7  1996 CO2       A         6.82      6
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Very much appreciated